# Line height gap - not centering content vertically

Tags: css

I am working on a jQuery mobile site, and for some reason, the `line-height` is not works as I expected. So I thought, maybe I made a mistake, so I tried it with a simple empty page, also on jsfiddle. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uwakdf1m/1/) link. As I remember, I did it a million times, to center an element vertically in another element.

So, when you see the result, you see, there red box is not in the center of the green box. I mesured, at the top, there are 22px, and at the bottom there are 16px.

Can anybody explain me, why is this happens, and how can I fix it?

```
<div style="height: 60px; width: 200px; line-height: 60px; border: 1px solid #0f0; box-sizing: border-box">
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 40px;  border: 1px solid #f00; box-sizing: border-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe not best solution, but try adding `text-align:center;` into outer div.

Comment: I want to center it vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the baseline, I think it's setting the baseline according to where the inherent font size would be vertically centered.

Comment: it is something like that you want? http://jsfiddle.net/uwakdf1m/3/

Comment: @dippas Yes, but can you just tell me, why isn't my first one is works? What makes the different space between top and bottom?

Comment: The method you used works perfectly for single line of text. Line-height is used for text. Better choose other centering option. Google 'centering the unknown'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the rendered font size. You can set the font size of the container to `20px` which will allow for the text baseline to center to the height of your inner block. If you look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2bmowco/)**, you see the difference between a block with the font size and without the font size.

The main reasoning for this is that `line-height` is a text property, and made to effect textual elements. It can be bent to work in other situations, though.

All I did for this was to add a `font-size` of `20px` to the parent div:

```
<div style="height: 60px; width: 200px; line-height: 60px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #0f0; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 20px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 40px; line-height: 40px; border: 1px solid #f00; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `position: absolute` to get it where you want http://jsfiddle.net/uwakdf1m/4/

```
    <div style="height: 60px; width: 200px; line-height: 60px; border: 1px solid #0f0; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">

    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 40px; border: 1px solid #f00; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;/*half height of this element*/"></div>

</div>
```

You'll need to put `position: relative` on the container div and it won't flow with other elements, but it's definitely centered this way.